# how to change div when ajax query returns no data

Tags: jquery, load, scroll

Am using jquery/ajax to fetch more when the browse is at 40% scrolling.

Here is the query script;

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var fetching = false;

        function lastPostFunc() {
            fetching = true;
                $('div#loadmorebutton').html('<a>Loading...pls wait</a>');
                $.post("loadmore.php?id=1&lastid="+$(".postitem:last").attr("id"),

        function(data){
            if (data != "") {
                    $(".postitem:last").after(data);
                        setTimeout(function(){
                        fetching = false;
                        },300);
                        $('div#loadmorebutton').empty();
                    } 
            });
        };


$(window).scroll(function(){
    var bufferzone = $(window).scrollTop() * 0.40;
    if (!fetching && ($(window).scrollTop() + bufferzone > ($(document).height()- $(window).height() ) )){
    lastPostFunc();
    } 
});
```

});

And the loading more div is;

```
<div id="loadmorebutton">Loading...pls wait</div>
```

Everything works great but when it reaches the last content or there's no more content to load, I want the "Loading...pls wait" to change to something like "No more content to load". At the moment, it stays the same "Loading...pls wait". What must I do?

NB. The following script works and does the change from "loading more" to "no more content to load". The reason am not using this script is cause it is triggered only when you reach the bottom of the screen which results in a double load or triple a times. Tried combining the codes but it still doesn't work.

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
        if($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()){
            $('div#loadmorebutton').show();
            $.ajax({url: "loadmore.php?id=01&lastid=" + $(".postitem:last").attr("id"),
        success: function(html){
                    if(html){
                        $("#postswrapper").append(html);
                        $('div#loadmorebutton').hide();
                    }else{
                        $('div#loadmorebutton').html('<a>No more posts to show.</a>');
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you will get a message from the server when there is no more content see this [Server codes](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/reference/article.php/3472941/Server-Response-Codes.htm). When you get that you should be able to set a message based on that. Check out the complete settings when you run the AJAX. Look for this '(jqXHR, textStatus)' on here: [AJAX properties](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) that should return the message, set a rule then you can update the DOM.

Comment: Thanx Cool. I am not a programmer, am a designer just trying my hands on some script. Just want someone to be able to edit the above script to do what I want it to do.